# XML in Scala - Elem method with minimizeEmpty Boolean

Tags: scala, xml-parsing, scala-2.10

Elem(prefix, label, attribs, scope, child) method is deprecated in Scala 2.10 and Elem(prefix, label, attribs, scope, minimizeEmpty, child) should be used. However at least on empty elements the new apply method has a different behavior. Deprecated version works in this way:

```
val inputXML = <PC Price="100" CurrencyCode="USD"/>
val rule1 = new RewriteRule {
    override def transform(n: Node): Seq[Node] = n match {
        case Elem(prefix, "PC", attribs, scope, content @ _*)  => 
            Elem(prefix, "Mac", attribs, scope, content:_*)
        case other => other
    }
}

println(new RuleTransformer(rule1).transform(inputXML))
```

which prints:

```
List(<Mac Price="100" CurrencyCode="USD"/>)
```

But when using the new Elem method, matching does not work:

```
val inputXML = <PC Price="100" CurrencyCode="USD"/>
val rule1 = new RewriteRule {
    override def transform(n: Node): Seq[Node] = n match {
        case Elem(prefix, "PC", attribs, scope, minimizeEmpty, content @ _*)  => 
            Elem(prefix, "Mac", attribs, scope, true, content:_*)
        case other => other
    }       
}

println(new RuleTransformer(rule1).transform(inputXML))
```

The above code returns:

```
<PC Price="100" CurrencyCode="USD"/>
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? I'm using Scala 2.10.2.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one `unapply` method in the `Elem`:

```
def unapplySeq(n: Node): Option[(String, String, scala.xml.MetaData, scala.xml.NamespaceBinding, Seq[scala.xml.Node])]
```

It returns `Tuple5`, but you are trying to use it like it returns `Tuple6`. You can't get `minimizeEmpty` with `unapplySeq` method.

```
val inputXML = <PC Price="100" CurrencyCode="USD"/>
val rule1 = new RewriteRule {
    override def transform(n: Node): Seq[Node] = n match {
        case Elem(prefix, "PC", attribs, scope, content @ _*)  => 
            Elem(prefix, "Mac", attribs, scope, true, content:_*)
        case other => other
    }       
}

println(new RuleTransformer(rule1).transform(inputXML))
// List(<Mac Price="100" CurrencyCode="USD"/>)
```

But I guess there is a bug here. This method should be named `unapply` to show a compilation error:

```
object ElemHelper {
  def unapply(n: Node): Option[(String, String, scala.xml.MetaData, scala.xml.NamespaceBinding, Seq[scala.xml.Node])] = Elem.unapplySeq(n)
}

val rule1 = new RewriteRule {
    override def transform(n: Node): Seq[Node] = n match {
        case ElemHelper(prefix, "PC", attribs, scope, minimizeEmpty, content @ _*)  => 
            Elem(prefix, "Mac", attribs, scope, true, content:_*)
        case other => other
    }       
}

// <console>:16: error: wrong number of arguments for object ElemHelper
```

I've created a [bug report](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7623).